# Who are these tribes mentioned in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: mahabharata, history, ancestry, geography

[Section LXV of Shanti Parva of Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a064.htm) mentions a conversation between Indra and Mandhatri that is narrated by Bhishma Pitamah to the Pandavas. It mentions many tribes:

> Mandhatri said, 'What duties should be performed by the **Yavanas, Kiratas, Gandharvas, Chinas, Savaras, Barbaras, Sakas, Tusharas, Kankas, Pathavas, Andhras, Madrakas, Paundras, Pulindas, Ramathas, Kamvojas,** the several castes that have sprung up from Brahmanas and Kshatriyas, the Vaisyas, and the Sudras, that reside in the dominions of (Arya) kings?

We are familiar with the probable locations of a few of them such as Yavanas identified with the Greeks in later Indian texts and Chinas with the Chinese. Andhras is also a recognizable group as are the Kiratas who were mountain-dwelling hunters.

**My question is - Can someone identify each of these groups conclusively based on the information in scriptures?**

Please feel free to add other such tribes in the list as well!